# QUnit test coverage

Tags: unit-testing, google-apps-script, code-coverage

How can I automatically measure my QUnit test code coverage in Google Apps Script?  It appears that [Blanket.js](http://blanketjs.org/) doesn't natively support this scenario.

Comment: Apps Script runs on Google's servers.  However, Apps Script can also create a Web App.  So, do you want to implement QUnit for Apps Script server code, or in a Web App client code?  Apps Script can not import external code at run time.  Any implementation would need to have the code saved in a ".gs" file.  And whether any code to run QUnit is compatible with Apps Script or not, I have no idea.

Comment: Yes, I run my QUnit suite on the Apps Script server side. My hunch when posting was that this was difficult or impossible.

Comment: I actually think that it *might* be possible, but unless someone has already figured it out, and publicly posted code on GitHub, I don't know how easy it would be to implement.  There might be someone here on StackOverflow who can give you a better answer, but you could also ask at: [Link to Apps Script community](https://plus.google.com/u/0/communities/102471985047225101769)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, if it works with Google Apps Script, but have you tried [Chutzpah](https://github.com/mmanela/chutzpah)

It at least provides test coverage stats.